# Class must be a child class of Doctrine_Record error on php symfony doctrine:insert-sql

Tags: php, mysql, symfony-1.4, doctrine-1.2

I have a problem generating my tables using the command:

```
php symfony doctrine:insert-sql
```

It returns me the following error:

```
>> doctrine  creating tables


  Class "Complaint" must be a child class of Doctrine_Record


PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function evictAll() on a non-object in D:\Internet\PHP\ijzerleeuw_bezoekrapporten\lib\vendor\symfony\lib\plugins\sfDoctri
nePlugin\lib\vendor\doctrine\Doctrine\Connection.php on line 1239
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() D:\Internet\PHP\ijzerleeuw_bezoekrapporten\symfony:0
PHP   2. include() D:\Internet\PHP\ijzerleeuw_bezoekrapporten\symfony:14
PHP   3. sfDatabaseManager->shutdown() D:\Internet\PHP\ijzerleeuw_bezoekrapporten\lib\vendor\symfony\lib\database\sfDatabaseManager.class.php:0
PHP   4. sfDoctrineDatabase->shutdown() D:\Internet\PHP\ijzerleeuw_bezoekrapporten\lib\vendor\symfony\lib\database\sfDatabaseManager.class.php:134
PHP   5. Doctrine_Manager->closeConnection() D:\Internet\PHP\ijzerleeuw_bezoekrapporten\lib\vendor\symfony\lib\plugins\sfDoctrinePlugin\lib\database\sfDoctr
ineDatabase.class.php:165
PHP   6. Doctrine_Connection->close() D:\Internet\PHP\ijzerleeuw_bezoekrapporten\lib\vendor\symfony\lib\plugins\sfDoctrinePlugin\lib\vendor\doctrine\Doctrin
e\Manager.php:580
PHP   7. Doctrine_Connection->clear() D:\Internet\PHP\ijzerleeuw_bezoekrapporten\lib\vendor\symfony\lib\plugins\sfDoctrinePlugin\lib\vendor\doctrine\Doctrin
e\Connection.php:1268
```

This is my schema.yml, which I used to generate the model (php symfony doctrine:build-mdeol):

```
InspectionReport:
  actAs: { Timestampable: ~ }
  columns:
    customer_id:    { type: integer(5), notnull: true }
    username:       { type: string(255), notnull: true }
    start_time:     { type: string(5) }
    end_time:       { type: string(5) }
    type:           { type: string(5) }
    reason:         { type: string(4) }
    contact:        { type: string(5) }
    subject:        { type: string(5) }
    remarks:        { type: string(5000) }
    emailaddresses: { type: string(5) }
  relations:
    Complaints:
      class: Complaint
      refClass: ComplaintInspectionReport
      local: id
      foreign: complaint_id
    Reviews:
      class: Review
      refClass: ReviewInspectionReport
      local: id
      foreign: review_id

ComplaintInspectionReport:
  columns:
    complaint_id:  { type: integer(4), primary: true }
    inspection_report_id: { type: integer, primary: true }
  relations:
    Complaint:  { onDelete: CASCADE, local: complaint_id, foreign: id }
    InspectionReport: { onDelete: CASCADE, local: inspection_report_id, foreign: id }

ReviewInspectionReport:
  columns:
    review_id:  { type: integer, primary: true }
    inspection_report_id: { type: integer, primary: true }
  relations:
    Review:  { onDelete: CASCADE, local: review_id, foreign: id }
    InspectionReport: { onDelete: CASCADE, local: inspection_report_id, foreign: id }

Complaint:
  columns:
    id:            { type: integer, notnull: true }
    description:   { type: string(32), notnull: true }
    contact:       { type: string(32) }
    remark:        { type: string(50) }

Review:
  columns:
    id:            { type: integer, notnull: true }
    description:   { type: string(32), notnull: true }
    contact:       { type: string(32) }
    remark:        { type: string(50) }
    grade:         { type: string(1) }
    email_address: { type: string(32) }
```

And the schema.sql I generated from the model/schema (php symfony doctrine:build-sql):

```
CREATE TABLE complaint (id BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT, description VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL, contact VARCHAR(32), remark VARCHAR(50), PRIMARY KEY(id)) ENGINE = INNODB;
CREATE TABLE complaint_inspection_report (complaint_id INT, inspection_report_id BIGINT, PRIMARY KEY(complaint_id, inspection_report_id)) ENGINE = INNODB;
CREATE TABLE inspection_report (id BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT, customer_id BIGINT NOT NULL, username VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, start_time VARCHAR(5), end_time VARCHAR(5), type VARCHAR(5), reason VARCHAR(4), contact VARCHAR(5), subject VARCHAR(5), remarks TEXT, emailaddresses VARCHAR(5), created_at DATETIME NOT NULL, updated_at DATETIME NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(id)) ENGINE = INNODB;
CREATE TABLE review (id BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT, description VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL, contact VARCHAR(32), remark VARCHAR(50), grade VARCHAR(1), email_address VARCHAR(32), PRIMARY KEY(id)) ENGINE = INNODB;
CREATE TABLE review_inspection_report (review_id BIGINT, inspection_report_id BIGINT, PRIMARY KEY(review_id, inspection_report_id)) ENGINE = INNODB;
ALTER TABLE complaint_inspection_report ADD CONSTRAINT complaint_inspection_report_complaint_id_complaint_id FOREIGN KEY (complaint_id) REFERENCES complaint(id) ON DELETE CASCADE;
ALTER TABLE complaint_inspection_report ADD CONSTRAINT ciii FOREIGN KEY (inspection_report_id) REFERENCES inspection_report(id) ON DELETE CASCADE;
ALTER TABLE review_inspection_report ADD CONSTRAINT riii FOREIGN KEY (inspection_report_id) REFERENCES inspection_report(id) ON DELETE CASCADE;
ALTER TABLE review_inspection_report ADD CONSTRAINT review_inspection_report_review_id_review_id FOREIGN KEY (review_id) REFERENCES review(id) ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

If I run the SQL manually it works fine, but when using doctrine:insert-sql it returns me errors.

I'm thinking of an error in my schema, but can't seem to get a hold of it. Or maybe it's something totally different.

Comment: Your schema is ok. Can we see model class for `Complaint` ? (`lib/model/doctrine/Complaint.class.php` & `lib/model/doctrine/ComplaintTable.class.php`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was wrong, I just generated classes and didn't try to load the sql.

In fact you have few errors:

- you shouldn't define a column `id` for a table, only if you don't need it to the primary key, not incremented, etc .. otherwise it will cause trouble to Doctrine
- for each intermidate table (`ComplaintInspectionReport` & `ReviewInspectionReport`) you don't have to redefine `relations`. If they are properly define in the parent class, you don't need them here
- be careful about `integer` type. Doctrine will always use `integer` but if you define a foreign with `integer(4)` that leads to an id auto generated by Doctrine, the relation will fail when insert sql. Because on one side you have `integer` and on the other `integer(4)`.
- finally, be careful about your `local` key defined in `InspectionReport`. You use `id` twice but you have to define the local key for the intermediate table, not the current one. So you will have to set `inspection_report_id` for both.

Here is the fixed schema:

```
InspectionReport:
  actAs: { Timestampable: ~ }
  columns:
    customer_id:    { type: integer(5), notnull: true }
    username:       { type: string(255), notnull: true }
    start_time:     { type: string(5) }
    end_time:       { type: string(5) }
    type:           { type: string(5) }
    reason:         { type: string(4) }
    contact:        { type: string(5) }
    subject:        { type: string(5) }
    remarks:        { type: string(5000) }
    emailaddresses: { type: string(5) }
  relations:
    Complaints:
      class: Complaint
      refClass: ComplaintInspectionReport
      local: inspection_report_id
      foreign: complaint_id
    Reviews:
      class: Review
      refClass: ReviewInspectionReport
      local: inspection_report_id
      foreign: review_id

ComplaintInspectionReport:
  columns:
    complaint_id:  { type: integer, primary: true }
    inspection_report_id: { type: integer, primary: true }

ReviewInspectionReport:
  columns:
    review_id:  { type: integer, primary: true }
    inspection_report_id: { type: integer, primary: true }

Complaint:
  columns:
    description:   { type: string(32), notnull: true }
    contact:       { type: string(32) }
    remark:        { type: string(50) }

Review:
  columns:
    description:   { type: string(32), notnull: true }
    contact:       { type: string(32) }
    remark:        { type: string(50) }
    grade:         { type: string(1) }
    email_address: { type: string(32) }
```

Do not forget to clear your cache before trying to re-insert sql.

Comment: Thank you for the help with my schema, but unfortunately I'm still getting the 'Class "Complaint" must be a child class of Doctrine_Record' error. I cleared my cache, deleted the old model, form and filter classes, re-build the model, sql and tried the insert-sql. Could it have to do with the Symfony version? I use, symfony version 1.4.12-DEV (project location\lib\vendor\symfony\lib) because it's an older project.

Comment: I tried updating the symfony version to the latest 1.4.19 but that didn't make a difference...

Comment: You tried `php symfony doctrine:build --all` ? Otherwise I do not have other idea .. you must have something specific that deals with Complaint class. You have to search on all your project ..

Comment: Another thing I tried, deleting the Complaint models and relations. I ran on the same error except for the Review, so I deleted all those models and ran it again, for InspectionReport alone it generates it, but for the others it doesnt...

Comment: With `code`php symfony doctrine:build --all`code` it works... I'm still not getting why this does work.

Comment: Well maybe the sql wasn't regenerated when using only `insert-sql` where `build --all` regenerate it.